# block navigation causing divs to move when set to relative?

Tags: css, html

I'm working on this website.

www.firmtechnologysolutions.us

I'm having a bizarre problem. I'm doing some fixes for css and navs right now. Whenever I click the navs like #services or #about it causes my divs to shift. I suspect its because I have them set up relative to each other. Is there some way to correct this problem?

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Firm Technology Solutions</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="home main" style="display: block;">
    <div class="content">
        <a href="#top" class="scroll-it active"></a>
<ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="#mainContainer" class="scroll-it">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services" class="scroll-it">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about" class="scroll-it">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contacts" class="scroll-it">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>  
    <div id ="mainContainer" class ="home-slide slide">
        <div id = "Logo">
            <img src="images/ftslogo.png">
                <h1>Managed Information Services for Small Business</h1>
                    <h2>Simple & Affordable IT Solutions to get you up and running</h2>
            <div class ="contactButton">
                <img src="images/contactButton.png">
            </div>
        </div>   
    <div id ="mainContainer2"></div>
        <div id = "mainContainer3"></div>
            <div id ="about" class ="about-slide slide">
            <h1>At Firm Technology Solutions, we are all about customer service. <br> We know that our customer's time is valuable.<br> Waiting around all day to get a fix on a minor problem on your email or server means you lose money. <br>Our service creed is: efficency.<br> We get on your problem as soon as you report it and try to resolve it ASAP.</h1>
            <p>Simple Solutions</p>
                <h2>We determine with our clients what kind of technology would fit <br>
                their business best by creating an action plan.
                </h2>
            <p>Affordable Solutions</p>    
                <h2>After we create our action plan we determine where we can cut costs for <br> deployment, overhead, and matainence costs. </h2>
            <p>The Firm Gauruntee</p>
                <h2>We gaurntee our work 100%. <br> As a locally based New Jersey business we understand that our clients don't want to talk to someone 2000 miles away.<br> On top of our remote administration service. <br>We offer full in person consultations to handle everything from A to Zip.</h2>
        </div>
            <div ="services" class ="services-slide slide" >
                <h1>Services</h1>
            </div>
                <div id = "serviceIcons">
                    <div class = "icon1">
                        <img src="images/icon1.png">
                            <p>Managed Information Services</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class ="icon2">
                            <img src="images/icon2.png">
                                <p>Networking</p>
                        </div>
                            <div class ="icon3">
                                <img src="images/icon3.png">
                                    <p>Remote Services</p>
                            </div>
                                <div class="icon4">
                                    <img src="images/icon3.png">
                                        <p>Web Design</p>
                                </div>
                </div>

    <div id = "contacts" class ="contact-slide slide">
        <h3>Contact us for more information!</h3>
                  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <p>
              <label for="Name">Name</label>
              <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="40" />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="Email">Email</label>
              <input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" size="40" />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="Discription">Tell us about the job<br />
              </label>
              <textarea name="Discription" id="Discription" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
            </p>
          </form>

    </div>

</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://www.elli.nu/potatis/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.backstretch("http://www.wallpapersmood.com/uploads/2010-09/green-plants-nature-wallpaper/1285552282-AE04VJ2.jpg");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce it... What browser are you using?

Comment: when you say shift do you mean it jumps down? or do they unalign? I am trying to reproduce what you mean and don't understand what you want that actually happens

Comment: when you click on a link...the divs shift out of alignment. I think its because when you use block - I should have used a combo of span/section classes instead of class/id...